# Getting WebPage to use a specific URL to download HTML resources

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qwebpage

I have a Qt program that downloads webpages (HTML), parses them and then generates its own HTML which is then displayed with `QWebPage`. Some times the HTML that I download contains `IMG` tags, which work fine when the `src` attribute contains a full URL. However, some times the `IMG` tag might use a relative path like:

```
<IMG SRC="images/foo.png" />
```

Since I know the URL that should be prepended to the `SRC` my first thought was to just tack it onto my resulting HTML when I'm parsing. However, this is proving more difficult than I anticipated and now I'm wondering if there's a better way.

If there any mechanism/property with QWebPage that I can say "use this URL for relative paths"? Or maybe someone can suggest a better way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: From the question it's not clear why relative paths are not resolving.  Please provide some sample code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Could you try calling QDir::setCurrent() to the folder of your .html file ? Maybe it can help resolve relative paths. I'm not sure though.

Comment: @MrEricSir I use QNetworkManager (et al) to get the HTML of the page I want, but it's not that HTML I'm actually displaying. I do some parsing/processing/manipulating and generate my own HTML. Then I simply call QWebView::setHtml.

Comment: @ch0kee I'm not sure the images are ever actually downloaded from my initial QNetworkRequest. I wonder if there is a way to get the images in a single QNetworkReply and then I could just process the MIME parts of the response...hmm..

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you mentioned that you're using [QWebView::setHtml()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebview.html#setHtml).  The second, optional parameter of this method sets the URL to use for resolving relative paths.  According to the documentation:

> External objects such as stylesheets or images referenced in the HTML
>   document are located relative to baseUrl.

Setting that parameter should be all that's needed here.